# Criteria to apply Restrictions and Projection then count distinct results

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, count, distinct

I'm trying to perform the following functionality using Criteria, but it's giving me a Run-time error indicating an error in SQL.

```
 var query = session.CreateCriteria<TableName>()
                       .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
                            .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Property1", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere))
                            .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Property2", keyword, MatchMode.Anywhere)));

query.SetProjection(Projections.Count(Projections.Distinct(
                                    Projections.ProjectionList()
                                    .Add(Projections.Property("Property1"))
                                    .Add(Projections.Property("Property3"))
                                    )));
```

The table mapping looks like this:

```
public class TableName
{
     public int Property1 {get;set;}
     public int Property2 {get;set;}
     public int Property3 {get;set;}
     public int Property4 {get;set;}
}
```

I need to count Distinct Results Based on my Projections, I don't want to count the results as a whole row!

Can anyone please help me with this?

***----------UPDATE----------***

This what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
select Count(*)

from 
(
    select distinct Property1 , Property2 
    from tableName
    where Property1 like '%t%' or Property3 like '%t%'
) As x
```

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria, if they could ever be translated, would result in an SQL like:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT Property1, Property3) 
FROM TableName 
WHERE Property1 LIKE '%keyword%' OR Property2 LIKE '%keyword%'
```

which would not work. Use

```
Projections.RowCount()  or  Projections.RowCountInt64()
```

for a COUNT(*) equivalent. 
Possibly, a GROUP BY clause makes sense (instead of DISTINCT). (I hope you don't need an Int64 result count when searching with LIKE '%keyword%'! ;-)

Comment: I've tried RowCount, but it doesn't eliminate the duplicate rows that results when Projection is made on only two columns! and that's what I need!

Comment: Please check the question Update above

Comment: I think I can't help at the moment, had to find out myself. My idea was count(...) with group by, but it will count only the number of duplicates grouped into one row, not all result rows.